# Validating order of method call

Tags: java

A class named `OutgoingItems` has 2 methods: `getNextItem()` and `hasItems()` .

In the current implementation `getNextItem()` is getting into a endless loop if `hasItems() == true`.

Is there a way to validate in the code that this method is not being called unless the condition for `hasItems() == true` has been checked first?

Maybe some sort of relevant annotation for static analysis? 
Assume that implementation changing is hard and there's a change that one can't just do it.

Answer (score 0):

*What you describe sounds semantically weird, surely calling `getNextItem()` doesn't make sense unless `hasItems()` **is** true?*

Anyway, the idea is the same, whichever way your logic works: wrap your `OutgoingItems` objects into a new class that checks the condition for you. I did the check with `assert` but you can choose whatever way you like.

```
public class OutgoingItemsDelegate {
   private final OutgoingItems items;

   public OutgoingItemsDelegate(OutgoingItems items) {
       this.items = items;
   }

   public boolean hasItems() {
       return items.hasItems();
   }

   public Object getNextItem() {
       assert !items.hasItems();
       // alternatively you can do this:
       // if (items.hasItems()) throw new IllegalStateException("hasItems() must not be true");
       return items.getNextItems();
   }    
}
```

There is of course a slight performance and space overhead you might have to pay with this solution, and the ideal solution is to fix `OutgoingItems` itself, but failing that, it's a viable option.

*Please note that for the `assert` statement to be evaluated, you need to use the `-ea` flag on the command line.